# Call for community action: Can someone update this theme?

Tags: support

http://userstyles.org/styles/44566/gaming-se-black-edition

I am using this style and I am sure others are using it. It would need a refresh for a couple of things:

- Change the highlight color from white to the greenish color used when you click on a notification or follow a direct link.
- Change the hover color for some comments and links from white to greenish.
- Update review queue coloring, it is all white.

There are some others that I may have overseen, but I don't have access to all community tools. I would do it myself, but I am bad at website hacking, even though I do know css and html. I fixed some of the above problems, but I don't have enough time to maintain it, since my free time is very volatile over the years. So if anyone from the community, preferably a long time user, has some spare time to keep this maintained, I am sure it would make a lot of people very happy, including me.

ps.: I know this is not the responsibility of stack exchange, but I think it does not hurt to ask here.

Comment: I've actually been thinking about doing it for a while now.. I'll let you know if I do get to it anytime soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've made one that is exactly the same style but changes all the white I could find to a green. Any feedback would be appreciated.

[Arqade SE Dark Style](http://userstyles.org/styles/100930/arqade-se-dark-style)

I understand that this shouldn't necessarily be posted here, but I thought I would at least give it a try considering I already had done this for my personal use. Will update as necessary.